# How has Magneto aged so gracefully?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, magneto

Magneto currently resides with Cyclops on utopia and is barely showing any signs of aging, despite being born in the 1920s. I realize that this is also the case for many other characters in cartoons and comics who aren't portrayed by actors and thus aren't constrained by consistent casting.

I know in the *X-Men: Evolution* cartoon he undergoes some process to heighten his mutant abilities, which also seems to have strengthened him in general, but this is the only instance of his age being reduced or otherwise fortified that I can find. I also know he was supposedly 'de-aged' but it turns out that was merely a clone.

How has he aged so gracefully then?

Comment: Is long life a side effect of the mutant gene?

Comment: I expect we'll see him soon ousted as leading the resurgence of the magnetic anti-aging movement, and an investor in one of the many companies (unnamed to not be mistaken as advertising) seeking to corner the market ... one such slogan: "Join the Superhuman Beings"

Comment: Maybe he was born with it, maybe it’s Maybelline. We may never know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magneto was de-aged by Alpha the Ultimate Mutant in [Defenders 15-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_%28comics%29#cite_note-29)...he was later re-aged by the Shi'ar Eric The Red to a body in its 30s or 40s (Uncanny X-Men 104).

Given that the forward aging of most people in the Marvel Universe is slowed, he should still be in that range physically. Mentally, though, he is the age he should be.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a mundane answer, but aside from all of the age-changing comic bookiness, I have another option:

This is a man who has spent almost every day for years prepping for, training for, being in or ending a fight, both using his powers, and other wise. Basically, he's a life-long soldier, and one who has been put into extreme situations on the regular, and Eric Lensherr doesn't strike me as a man who would willingly let his edge slip.

There are many real world examples of former athletes, soldiers and martial artists who keep themselves fit by maintaining the practice of their skills. And there have been several examples of the older X-Men, even Charles himself, continually training to keep fit. Considering his dedication to the cause, it's not unlikely that Magneto does the same.